# "Methods for Lightning Experience" working in the Service Console but not in the Sales Console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, service-cloud-console, lightningnavigation, navigation-menu

I have embedded a custom lightning component on the record page of "Case". When I use the "Methods of Navigation Items" and "Methods for Workspace Tabs and Subtabs" within the ["Methods for Lightning Experience"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_lightning.htm) then I get results when opening the Case in the Service Console, but I do not get any when I open the Case in the Sales Console.

For example, the function "isConsoleNavigation" gives me 'true' in the Service Console, but 'false' in the Sales Console.

Service and Sales Cloud are slightliy differently set up, but as the "Case" record is also embedded in a Navigation Bar I wonder why it is not possible to call the Navigation Bar Items. Is it because the Workspace API is embedded in the component and not directly linked to the Navigation Bar?

Is there a workaround available?